# When instantiating a class, what is the difference between with and without parentheses/brackets?

Tags: python

Say I have a very simple class like the following:

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self): 
        self.myProp = 2
```

If I instantiate **using the parentheses/brackets**, everything works as I expect:

```
>>> a = myClass()
>>> a.myProp
2
```

However, **if I don't use the parentheses/brackets** on the two lines above, i.e.:

```
>>> a = myClass
```

I get the following error:

```
>>> a.myProp
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#45>", line 1, in <module>
a.myProp
AttributeError: class myClass has no attribute 'myProp'
```

If I print the object,

```
>>> a = myClass
>>> a
```

I get

```
<class __main__.myClass at 0x0275C538>
```

It seems that `a` is an instance of the class, but somehow is not initialized.

In other languages, I would expect a compile error if trying to cast a class instance into an object without initalizing it (e.g. in C#, `myClass a = new myClass();` would work fine but `myClass a = new myClass;` would return a compile error).

So my question is: what is, technically speaking, the object `a = myClass` without parentheses/brackets?

Comment: No, it's not an instance of the class, *it's the class object itself*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`a` is the class itself -- In python, classes are first class objects<sup>1</sup>.  You can pass them around as parameters, alias them to different names (as you've done in your example) and then you can instances from any reference that you have in the current namespace.

```
a = myClass  # a and myClass identical at this point.  The interpretter won't care which you use.
a_instance = a()  # instance of myClass

def make_instance(cls):
    return cls()

another_instance = make_instance(a)
yet_another_instance = make_instance(myClass)
```

You see, python doesn't have any "compile time checking" because really -- there is no compile time.  Python code gets interpreted at *runtime*.  True, you can have `SyntaxError`s pop up at when you *import* something, but that is still during runtime.

<sup><sup>1</sup>No pun intended</sup>

Comment: This makes a lot of sense to me, and since it definitely answers my question I will accept it as soon as I can (SO forbids me still). But I take chance to ask: what's the useful side? I mean, why would I want to cast a class into a variable? I ask it because I don't imagine it clearly and would love to know it with a simple explanatory example.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ - You don't *"cast a class into an object"*; classes *are* objects in Python, as is everything else including functions, methods, and even literals.  As for why you would want to pass a class object as an argument, consider an example using `map`:  `map(str, [1, 2, 3])`  `str` is a class object like `myClass` and is used in this case to build a list of `str` instances from the list of integers.

Comment: There's no "casting" involved in setting a variable equal to a class. Indeed, the name of the class is just another variable. There's nothing special about `MyClass` that isn't also true of `a`. I use this feature all the time, for example I can create several classes that all implement different algorithms for the same problem and can pass a function the class I want to perform the calculation so that the function can focus just on gathering the inputs and outputs.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @iCodez and wkschwartz, things are clearer.

Answer (score 11):

It's a reference to the class itself, rather than a reference to an instance of the class. Note the difference:

```
>>> a = myClass
>>> a
<class __main__.myClass at 0x10cd1de20>
>>> b = myClass()
>>> b
<__main__.myClass instance at 0x10cd8efc8>
```

Answer (score 3):

Everything in Python is an object and thus an instance of a class, *including classes*. There is nothing special about manipulating classes or passing them around as variables. Thus your variables `a` and `MyClass`, *which refer to the same object*, are just the object that is `MyClass`.

```py
>>> class R: pass # In Python 2, you would need class R(object): pass
>>> r = R()
```

Now we have two variables, `R` and `r`. `r` is an instance of class `R`. The trick here is that `R` is an instance of class `type`, which is why we call `R` a class. Both `r` and `R` are instances of `object`, which is why we call both of them objects. And `R` is a subclass of class `object` because `R` is a class.

```py
>>> isinstance(R, type)
True
>>> isinstance(r, R)
True
>>> issubclass(R, object)
True
>>> isinstance(r, object)
True
>>> isinstance(type, object)
True
>>> isinstance(type, type)
True
```

Every Python object is an instance of `object` and every Python class is a subclass of `object` and every Python class is an instance of `type`.

Note that what I'm saying is true in Python 3 and for Python 2 "new style" classes. Do not concern yourself with Python old-style classes.